# Can't remove horizontal scrollbar from iframe

Tags: iframe, scroll, overflow, hidden

I have an iframe that should have a vertical scrollbar, but I do not want the horizontal scrollbar to appear. Nothing I do is making the scrollbar go away, other than putting scrolling="no" in the iframe tag, but I can't do this because I need the vertical scrollbar.

I tried the following things to get rid of the scrollbar:

```
<iframe src="xxx"  style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll" height="800"></iframe>
```

and

```
<iframe src="xxx"  scrolling="yes" horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="yes" height="800"></iframe>
```

but the horizontal scrollbar just won't go away.

[You can view the page here](http://www.chkd.org/Our-Services/Rehabilitative-Services-and-Therapy/Requests/Observation-Hours-Request-Form/), though you need to set the height on the iframe to 800 in order to get the scrolling issue (the iframe resizes itself on Chrome, but it doesn't on ie8 which is why I need vertical scrolling enabled)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues here.  First,  scrolling="no" is the proper way to disable scroll bars.  Of course that leaves your issue with IE8 not getting sized correctly.   I'd need to know more about the particular set up you have going... why can't you set a width to the iframe?

You could do:  width="100%" on your iframe to make sure it used all it could,  or you could look at using Javascript to set the width on page load.

Comment: I do have a width set to the iframe, but the contents of the iframe may be wider than that. I discovered that one of the pages being loaded has an object that has width:928px, which exceeds the width of my iframe; this is what's causing the horizontal scrollbar. However, I don't have access to the css file of the page that's being loaded in the iframe.

Comment: @user3784238  unfortunately that isn't possible.   you'll have to use something other than an iframe,  such as using a cURL server-side to retrieve the page and then apply your own CSS rules.